# Image shrinks by 1 pixel when hovering it for no reason

Tags: css

On the left sidebar of [this page](http://baiadesign.com/portfolio/) there are images whose opacity switches from 1 to 0.95 on hovering:

```
#div_port_left a img:hover {
    opacity: 0.95; 
}
```

But for some reason, the images don't just become slightly less visible on hovering, they also seem to shrink or some similar effect. I don't understand what causes this effect. I just want to change the opacity nothing else.

Comment: Is the size of `img` set in HTML? Is it displayed at the same size of the original image or is it scaled up/down? Which declarations apply to these when *not* hovered? How did you observe that there were 1px off? Is it in both directions or vertical or horizontal?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on the page you linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect you are seeing isn't actually a shrinking but the browser making a slightly different determination on a slightly transparent image than it did on a fully opaque one.  The source image (to pick on the first one) is 131x91 but you are asking the browser to scale this down to 88x60.  This means it will have to throw away some pixels.  Modern browsers all attempt to apply a filter to make the scaling look better but it isn't perfect.  to fix this scale your image to match the dimensions of your space and then the browser won't mess with it.

Comment: Ok so the solution is to display the actual source image. That's what I did before and it worked fine. I realize now that the problem started when I reduced the size of the images by reducing their container.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it in other browsers?

It may be that the browser's default CSS has borders for images when not hovered. Unlikely but possible. I suggest you take a look into using [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). I use it myself and find it helps a lot especially with cross browser compatibility.

Comment: Wow, I checked and the problem only occurs with FF (usually it's the contrary)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in Firefox 24.0 and Internet Explorer 10, and neither shrinks the image.

However, some browsers might use a different way of drawing images that have some effects applied to them, so in some specific browser you might experience a pixel difference.

You can try to apply an invisible effect by default, to see if there is a difference in the browser where you see the pixel difference:

```
#div_port_left a img {
  opacity: 0.99999; 
}
```

As the pixel difference only occurs in some browsers, you might choose to just accept it as a browser difference.